# How to use Material-UI with React and ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, material-ui

It is possible of using Material-UI + React + ASP.net MVC?
I know about React.net and ASP.net MVC, but I can not figure how to integrate Material-UI to ASP.net MVC project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't require `react` inside `webpack.ProvidePlugin`

Just Remove

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            React: "React", react: "React", "window.react": "React", "window.React": "React"
        }),
    ],
```

and remove this also

```
 externals: {
        // Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
        // bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
        react: 'React'
    }
```

and need to add `es2015` in `presets`

```
{
    test: /\.jsx$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i got it. Thank You. Also, I create separate .babelrc file and add presets: ['es2015', 'react'].

Answer (score 0):

You just need to integrate `material ui` into `react`, and create a bundle using `webpack` in `react`, after that integrate/import that bundle in you `asp.net mvc view`. Thats it...

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to the react, so I do not understand how to organize it all. Now I'm trying what you said. I will write the results afterwards